# 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' duplicate section defined -IIS7

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis, iis-7

i saw several post about : 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined on internet

i try to change the application pool it is not working

also in online, i found to commenting few lines, but i do not know which webconfig file i need  to pick up for that

problem is: i am not able to load css due to this issue :

[image]

full image is : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzydB.png)

please help me to instruct step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove line 14 in the web.config file.

Comment: in which web.config file?? that's what i am wondering ! in my application there is no such line, in webconfig.

Comment: My first suggestion would be:
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MDSNQReports_PublishVersion\web.config 

but now I see you have a web.config file here too?
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MDSNQReports_PublishVersion\css\web.config